# ¿Es lo mismo "Leonor se va de España como su abuelo" que "Leonor se va de España, como su abuelo"?

Tags: sintaxis, puntuación, significado-en-contexto

Leo en Twitter:

> “Leonor se va de España, como su abuelo” es infinitamente más inocuo que “Leonor se va de España como su abuelo”. Esa coma debería estudiarse en cursos de protocolo diplomático.
>
> <sub>Bob Pop, Twitter. [10 febrero 2021](https://twitter.com/BobPopVeTV/status/1359526643350519811)</sub>

Para dar más contexto sobre la frase, puede leerse la noticia [*TVE releva a los responsables de un polémico rótulo sobre la princesa de Asturias y su marcha a estudiar a Gales: ‘Leonor se va de España, como su abuelo’*](https://elpais.com/television/2021-02-10/tve-releva-a-los-responsables-de-un-polemico-rotulo-sobre-la-princesa-de-asturias-y-su-marcha-a-estudiar-a-gales-leonor-se-va-de-espana-como-su-abuelo.html). Básicamente, un rótulo puesto en la televisión pública de España que provocó que los que redactaron perdieran su puesto.

En definitiva, y para centrar el debate en lo esencialmente lingüístico: ¿qué diferencia hay entre estas dos frases?

- *Leonor se va de España, como su abuelo*
- *Leonor se va de España como su abuelo*

La diferencia está únicamente en la coma que antecede a *como su abuelo*.

A mí ambas me suenan exactamente igual y la coma simplemente la veo como una inflexión para dar énfasis a la segunda cuando se lee en voz alta. Pero considero que tiene el mismo significado exacto. ¿Es así o, lingüísticamente, representan algo diferente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es la diferencia entre [oración subordinada adjetiva especificativa y explicativa](https://e-ducativa.catedu.es/44700165/aula/archivos/repositorio/4000/4101/html/5_subordinadas_adjetivas_especificativas_y_explicativas.html).

- Especificativa: *Subí a la montaña como tú*. Subí de la misma forma que tú (en chanclas, por ejemplo). La oración subordinada modifica el significado.
- Explicativa: *Subí a la montaña, como tú*. También subí a la montaña. La subordinada aporta información (indico que tú también), pero no modifica el sentido de la oración principal.

La princesa Leonor no se va de España de la misma forma que lo hizo su abuelo, por lo que la subordinada debe ser explicativa, con coma.